# Create a deep copy of a Collection to a ImmutableSortedSet upon initialization of a class in java

Tags: java, collections, clone, guava, immutability

I have an ImmutableSortedSet that is create on initialization of a class. For every object of this class i want the ImmutableSortedSet to have a deep copy (clone) of the elements stored in an Collection located in another file.

This is the collection with the original values (could also be a set)

```
public static final List<Quest> QUESTS = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the class i want to create with the ImmutableSortedSet

```
package com.vencillio.rs2.content.quest;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet;

public class QuestManager {

    private int questPoints = 0;
    private final Set<Quest> QUESTS = ImmutableSortedSet.copyOf(Quest.QUESTS); //This is only a shallow copy

    public int getQuestPoints() {
        return questPoints;
    }

    public void addQuestPoints(int amount) {
        questPoints += amount;
    }

    public void removeQuestPoints(int amount) {
        questPoints -= amount;
    }

    public Optional<QuestState> getQuestState(String name) {
        return getQuest(name).isPresent() ? Optional.of(getQuest(name).get().getQuestState()) : Optional.empty();
    }

    public void setQuestState(String name, QuestState state) {
        if(getQuest(name).isPresent())
            getQuest(name).get().setQuestState(state);
    }

    public Optional<Quest> getQuest(String name) {
        return QUESTS.stream().filter(quest -> quest.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findAny();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explained how to get a copy of a `Quest` in the first place, which is an aspect of *your* design.  In general, I'd write something like

```
import static com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;

Quest.QUESTS.stream()
   .map(quest -> copy(quest))
   .collect(toImmutableSortedSet(naturalOrder()));
```

Comment: 'Quest' Implements the Cloneable interface to get a copy. i used what you gave me and got it going essentially, what should i put for the Comparator argument in 'ImmutableSortedSet. My Quest class implements Comparable<Quest> and Comparator<Quest> but how can i use the comparator from that class if it is abstract?

Comment: Nothing should _ever_ implement both `Comparator` and `Comparable`.  _Never._  If you want to use the `Comparable` natural order, then use exactly what I wrote, because it uses the natural ordering.  If you want to use a `Comparator`, then make that another class, and then pass that into the code I wrote above instead of `naturalOrder()`.

Comment: `ImmutableSortedSet.naturalOrder()` returns a builder type where as `ImuutableSortedSet.toImmutableSortedSet()` is asking for a type of comparator. What should be put there? Thank you for your help, very clarifying.

Comment: `Comparator.naturalOrder()`, not `ImmutableSortedSet.naturalOrder()`.

Comment: Thanks! i was  using eclipse and for some odd reason it wasn't showing any of the static methods it had, just the class option. Solved! (How do i give you some reputation of some sort for your help?)